# Mgtwitter engine Login And logOut

Tags: iphone, mgtwitterengine

Hello I am using MGTwitterEngine to create twitter app.I created different views for followers list, user time line and so on... Once I login It will save user credentials with following code

```
- (void) storeCachedTwitterOAuthData: (NSString *) data forUsername: (NSString *) username {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject: data forKey: @"authData"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (NSString *) cachedTwitterOAuthDataForUsername: (NSString *) username 
{
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"authData"];
}
```

And I am passing consumer key and secret in view did appear . My question is should I write this consumer key  and this user credential code in all view.. or I can do it some other way? And how to logout from twitter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should delete cookies for log out thing..

like this..

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
for (cookie in [storage cookies])
{
    NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
    NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"twitter"];
    if(domainRange.length > 0)
    {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I define consumer secret and key as a constant, they are static, so I just have to import a header, or even better put them in a constants.h and import with the prefix file in all files.
2. Logging out:

   - [Logout using MGTwitterEngine ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977845/logout-using-mgtwitterengine)
   - [how to logout from Twitter in iPhone.I am using OAuth+MGTwitterEngine Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067837/how-to-logout-from-twitter-in-iphone-i-am-using-oauthmgtwitterengine-library), there is a clearAccessToken method in the engine class.